# Crop a fixed size image in Android

Tags: android, crop

I am trying to crop an image but I want to be able to set the cropped area to exactly 640px x 640px.  I want to prevent a user from cropping down to a really small area.  So  basically I would prefer to have a fixed height and width for the cropping area.  I have looked into several third party libraries but don't see solving this problem. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: "How can I do this?" -- start with one of the libraries and modify it to incorporate your desired feature.

Comment: @CommonsWare I did it. Check my answer and vote if it's what you mean :)

Answer (score 18):

I'd use one of these solutions:

1. https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop
2. https://github.com/edmodo/cropper

Both seems to be appropriate to solve your problem and for sure cover more edge cases, devices and other Android stuff just to be more stable and reliable.

**EDIT:**
I have introduced a few changes to `android-crop` and now you can use `withFixedSize(int width, int height)` to set fixed cropping area in pixels.

Looks like this:

```
 private void beginCrop(Uri source) {
        Uri outputUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(getCacheDir(), "cropped"));
        new Crop(source).output(outputUri).withFixedSize(640, 640).start(this);
    }
```

Here it's a [pull request.](https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop/pull/61)

Check full code at my github https://github.com/mklimek/android-crop/tree/newfeature_fied_size_crop.

You can clone build and add it to your project afterwards.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I also tried these two libraries, but neither one has a fixed cropping window.

Comment: @toobsco42 I edited my answer and I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: I tried to use your code but the method "withFixedSize" doesn't seem to exist in your github repo. Do you know how could I call this method?

Comment: @Shargotth android-crop owner has not added my pull request, You have to use my repo to build own android-crop and put a final .aar in your project https://github.com/mklimek/android-crop/tree/newfeature_fied_size_crop

Comment: very use full answers

Comment: After using this function Picture Zoom in Zoom out functionality Disabled.Kindly let me know how i can enable this

Answer (score 4):

There is a method you can useÆ

```
private void performCrop(){
    try {
        //call the standard crop action intent (the user device may not support it)
        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        //indicate image type and Uri
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(selectedImage, "image/*");
        //set crop properties
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        //indicate aspect of desired crop
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        //indicate output X and Y
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 640);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 640);
        //retrieve data on return
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        //start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);
    }
    catch(ActivityNotFoundException anfe){
        //display an error message
        String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support the crop action!";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

This part of code is what youøre interested in:

```
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 640);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 640);
```

You should call crop method like this:

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    if (requestCode == CAMERA && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        selectedImage = data.getData();
        performCrop();

    } 

    if (requestCode == UPLOAD && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        selectedImage = data.getData();
        performCrop();
    }

    if (requestCode == PIC_CROP && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        //get the cropped bitmap
        Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");

        // Do what you want to do with the pic here
    }



}
```

Comment: But this doesn't fix the cropping window. It would still be resizable.

Comment: what if you play around with 
        .putExtra("scale", true)
        .putExtra("scaleUpIfNeeded", true)

Try true/false variants

Comment: Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`: http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html

Comment: @CommonsWare: Did you read the source code of these libraries in your link, Thay also point to the default intent crop on Android: com.android.camera.action.CROP . So what else if we use it directly, these libraries as a helper, not differences.

Comment: @KhangTran: "Did you read the source code of these libraries in your link" -- yes, I did. You did not. "Thay also point to the default intent crop on Android: com.android.camera.action.CROP" -- the first one provides its own crop activity. The second one provides its own crop view. The third is a fork of the second. The last one no longer exists, but there are [plenty of other candidates](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45) nowadays.